# Find path to node, Tree C

Tags: c, tree

Hi i'm trying to find the path to a given node in a Tree.

I use the tree to analize all the possible pathways in a maze defined as a matrix of int.

Here's the matrix:

```
int room[20][20] =
{
  {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
};
```

1 means that there is a wall, 2 is the exit, 0 is free space

here's how i defined the node:

```
struct node
{
 int i,j; //NODE COORDS
 int key;
 struct node *right;
 struct node *left;
 struct node *up;
 struct node *down;
};
```

Here's the method i'm using to insert a node in the Tree:

```
void insert(int room[20][20], struct node **leaf, int i, int j)
{

    if( *leaf == 0 )
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->key = room[i][j];
        (*leaf)->i = i;
        (*leaf)->j = j;
        (*leaf)->left = 0;
        (*leaf)->right = 0;
        (*leaf)->up = 0;
        (*leaf)->down = 0;
    }
    else if((room[i][j+1]==0 || room[i][j+1]==2) && i<20 && j<20 && i>=0 && j+1>=0)//CHECK IF RIGHT IS FREE OR IS EXIT OF THE MAZE
    {
        (*leaf)->key = room[i][j+1];
        insert( room, &(*leaf)->right, i ,j+1 );
    }
    else if((room[i][j-1]==0 || room[i][j-1]==2) && i<20 && j<20 && i>=0 && j-1>=0)//CHECK IF LEFT IS FREE OR IS EXIT OF THE MAZE
    {
        (*leaf)->key = room[i][j-1];
        insert( room, &(*leaf)->left, i ,j-1 );
    }
    else if((room[i+1][j]==0 || room[i+1][j]==2) && i<20 && j<20 && i+1>=0 && j>=0)//CHECK IF DOWN IS FREE OR IS EXIT OF THE MAZE
    {
        (*leaf)->key = room[i+1][j];
        insert( room, &(*leaf)->down, i+1 ,j );
    }
    else if((room[i-1][j]==0 || room[i-1][j]==2) && i<20 && j<20 && i-1>=0 && j>=0)//CHECK IF UP IS FREE OR IS EXIT OF THE MAZE
    {
        (*leaf)->key = room[i-1][j];
        insert( room, &(*leaf)->up, i-1 ,j );
    }
}
```

Initialise the Tree:

```
struct node *root = 0;
for(i=0;i<400;i++)
insert(room,&root,0,0); //INITIALIZE THE TREE ANALIZING EVERY CELL OF THE MATRIX
```

Once i initialized the Tree like above i want to search for the key that has the value 2(exit) and be able to find the path from that node to the root node and gather the coords of every node in between them.

To do this once i find the node that has value 2 i want to find the parent of that node and so on until i find the root node, and every time i find a node in between them i want to store it's coords in an array, so later on i can use them to draw the path to the exit.

**How do i find the node that has value 2 in this case ?**

**How do i find the parent node of a given node in this case ?**

Comment: To help and understand your problem, could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `struct node` is also not described.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a general pathfinding question. One popular solution is to implement the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). How you end up structuring and traversing your data is up to you, but this algorithm describes how to get from point A to B (shortest distance, avoiding obstacles). You should be able to adopt this algorithm for your situation.